# Can't create a new Word document in WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, office-integration, word

Issue:

- If I open Word and create and save a file to my desktop, I can upload
  it to SharePoint with no issue.
- If I right click and create a Word document on my desktop machine I
  am unable to upload it to SharePoint.  I get the following error
  message (in both IE10 and Firefox):

> You must specify a value for the required field. The file name is invalid or the file is empty. A file name cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > | # { } % ~ &

- If I select new word document in SharePoint it also won't let me save
  the document.  No error message is given.

A colleague has no issue so I'm aware it is local to my machine.

I have a WSS 3.0 installation on Server 2003.
I have a Windows 7 desktop machine with Office 2010.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right click to create a new document, and don't modify the contents, it is empty, and to SharePoint's point, it is "invalid or the file is empty" and SharePoint won't accept it.

When you click to create a new document in SharePoint, are you entering any content into the document? Or are you just trying to save it empty?

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the issue.  Although strangely it does allow an empty .doc file and .xlsx file to be uploaded.

Comment: Glad that worked. My guess is that's due to the formatting. When you're in Word and open and save a blank doc, there's some formatting carried with it (margins, font, etc). When you right click and create new, it doesn't know what it is until you open it. It's quite odd.

Comment: Right that makes a little sense anyway.  This question actually occured due to a further issue I've found described in a new question I posted today.  Don't now if you're able to help with that.  It's sort of related.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74529/unable-to-save-a-new-word-document